# Can a windows bases R/RStudio connect to Linux based HDP SparkR node/cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, sparkr

I have a HDP cluster running on Linux nodes, It has Spark version which is greater than 1.4 installed on it so SparkR is already inbuilt. Also, both my R and RStudio applications are running on my desktop which is Windows 7 machine.
Now my question is can my Windows based RStudio connect to SparkR from my cluster Linux nodes and submit jobs or created data.frames, read/write data into HDFS?

Comment: I recommend extracting the latter part of your question to a separate question. Regarding the first part: is there a reason why you wouldn't want to use RStudio server?

Comment: As long as the master node of your Spark cluster is reachable via TCP/IP from your laptop, R should be able to talk to it and submit jobs. Just set accordingly the `master` argument of `spark_connect()` (sparklyr) / `sparkR.session()` (SparkR). The last part of your question is off-topic here - no "which one is better" kind of questions are allowed.

Comment: Hi Rick, I edited the question as appropriate. What i have right now is only a windows based RStudio desktop and RProject. I want to see if i can run SparkR on my current R/RStudio windows and Linux based HPC cluster, if this is possible i don't have to engineer Linux based R and RStudio server.

Comment: Hi Hristo, i edited my original posting as appropriate. Will you be able to point me to any documentation how to do it? there is lot of help relates to installing SparkR local install as well as installing RStudio , SparkR on one of the HPC cluster Linux nodes but i couldn't find any help relates to running R/RStudio on Windows and connecting to Linux based HPC cluster. thank you! i see same thing with RHDFS and rmr packages.